# How to instantiate an entity class in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot

I am writing a Springboot application, and I have been annotating the entity class with "component" so I can auto wire them in the controller class. I read up that such technique is wrong and bad. I want to know if there is a way that i can instantiate an entity class without having to use something like....

```
"EntityObject object = new EntityObject();"
```

every time?

Comment: why would you create an entity in the controller to begin with, create a DTO and map it to the entity to seperate what people send vs. what you save? Additionally not everything in spring needs to be managed by spring there is nothing wrong with doing `new EntityObject();` Spring doesn't handle everything.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe okay, but now the problem is how do i transfer the properties of an Entity object to a DTO object. I cant do "userDTO dto = new User Entity()"

Comment: Nope. Mapstruct or other mapping frameworks can help. You need to do somethings yourself even with Spring